# how to implement adding a price to an object without modifying the uml diagram c++

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, uml, abstract-class

I don't know how to implement adding a price to a menu so I don't change the uml chart.

Description of the requirements:

> Abstract class `Menu` has a purely virtual method `description()`.
> `Withlemon` and `Withcoffee` contains a menu and method
> `description()` that adds text “With lemon”, respectively “with
> coffee”, in the description of the menu contained.
>  The price of a
> menu which contains lemon increases by 4, the one with coffee costs an
> additional 5.
>  The `Breakfast` class is a menu without lemon and
> without coffee, the method description() returns the name of the menu.
> In the pizzeria restaurant there are 2 small dishes breakfast: Eggs
> and Omelet, at the price of 10 respectively 15.
>
> Create only methods and attributes that result from the UML diagram
> (just add specific things C ++ ex: constructors).

Here the UML diagram:
[image]

Here my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Menu {
private:
    int price = 0;
public:
    virtual string description() = 0;
    int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    

};
class WithLemon : public Menu {
private:
    Menu* meniu;
    
public:
    WithLemon() = default;
    WithLemon(Menu* n) :
        meniu{ n } {}
    string description() {
        return meniu->description() + " with lemon ";
    }
};

class WithCoffee : public Menu {
private:
    Menu* meniu;
public:
    WithCoffee(Menu* n) :
        meniu{ n } {
    }
    string description() {
        return meniu->description() + " with coffee ";
    }
};

class Breakfast : public Menu {
private:
      string name;
public:
    Breakfast(string n) :
        name{ n } {
    }
    string description() {
        return name;
    }
};

int main() {
    Breakfast a{"eggs"};
    WithCoffee transformer1{ &a };
    transformer1 = &a;
    cout << transformer1.description() << " " << transformer1.getPrice() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confuse. Price attribute is already at UML chart. Are you regarding to a getting method? BTW, is it part of an exam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problems with the diagram

First, the diagram doesn't correspond to the narrative:

- There is already a `price` and a `getPrice()`.  You can therefore do exactly as with description():  just provide your own implementation.
- Then, it doesn't show that `description` is purely virtual in `Menu`: the operation should have been shown in italic.
- In addition,  since that `WithLemon`, `WithCoffee` and `Breakfast` provide their own concrete implementation of `description()`, it should have been shown in these classes as well.

Hint:   `WithLemon` and `WithCoffee` are ***[decorators](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html)*** of `Menu`.

### Problems with the code

In the base class `Menu`,  since you have one virtual function, it's a good practice to give it a virtual destructor. Since you have a price and there's no way to change it afterwards, it should be included in the constructor:

```
class Menu {
private:
    int price;
public:
    Menu(int p=0) :  price{p} {} 
    ...
    virtual ~Menu() {}
};
```

Now you should also provide for the `price`, in `Breakfast`, again at construction.  A small advice: whenever you override a virtual function from a base class, use the keyword `override`; it will save you hours of debugging of nastry errors in the future :

```
class Breakfast : public Menu {
private:
      string name;
public:
    Breakfast(string n, int p) :
        name{ n }, Menu{ p}  {
    }
    string description() override {
        return name;
    }
};
```

You have well implemented the decorators. I'd just recommend to add the `override` keywords for the same reasons.

Finally,  to meet all the requirements, without contradicting the class-diagram,  you may make `getPrice()` virtual:  it's not a pure virtual function, since you provide a default implementation in the base `Menu`.  In the decorator,  you'd just override the method with a more specialized one:

```
class WithCoffee : public Menu {
private:
    Menu* meniu;
public:
    WithCoffee(Menu* n) :
        meniu{ n } {
    }
    string description() override{
        return meniu->description() + " with coffee ";
    }
    int getPrice() override{
        return meniu->getPrice()+5; 
    }
};
```

In my view, such overriding should be shown in the diagram.  But since your teacher didn't show the overriding of an abstract method (which is far more important),  he/she cannot complain that in your code override a method where a default implementation is provided.

Finally, you can test this:

```
Breakfast a{"eggs", 10};
WithCoffee breakfast_with_coffee { &a };
cout << breakfast_with_coffee.description() << " " << breakfast_with_coffee.getPrice() << endl;
```

Here the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nahpj3).

***Important remark:**  this is of course for learning purpose only.  In real world, you'd have methods to change the price.  Moreover,  decroators wouldn't just add hard-coded texts and amounts.  Finally,  you'd probably use smart pointers, instead of the error-prone raw pointers.*